# How to trigger a windows service to start when new folder or file created

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, triggers, windows-services, createprocess

I have a windows service that prints reports on start.I have two scenarios-
1.I want to start this service when a new folder has been created in my E:\here\ folder.How to accomplish this?
2 Also is it possible to trigger a service when a new row inserted into database table?how?

Please provide links for above queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to check if the specific folder is created in a specific location. When its created you can start the Windows Service.

`Creating FileSystemWatcher`

```
//Define this in the clas level
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
```

`Initializing`

```
private void InitializeWatcher()
{ 
  watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(NotifyChange);
  watcher.Path = @"E:\here\folder";
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

`Starting Windows Service when folder is created`

```
private void NotifyChange(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Name.Equals("FolerName",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
      new ServiceController("WindowsServiceName").Start();
   }
}
```

Comment: Am new to C# and windows services.. Do i have to create new service for the above or to include in the existing? tried but didnt work on many ways!

Comment: @mmu If you alreayd have a service then you have to give your service name here new ServiceController("WindowsServiceName").Start();. Which will start the windows service. Why are you using windows service ?

Comment: @ AccessDenied i have created a service to export .rdlc to pdf in VS2008.It needs to be triggered in two kinds of events - 1. When a new folder created in E:\here and access the file inside new folder to read and generate report based on it. 2.When a new row inserted in a DB table.Based on new row generate report.

Comment: Above code should start windows service when folder is created. Did you give the correct service name and try. Make sure your service is started and running.

Comment: is there any database monitoring class to watch table insertion to start service?

Comment: How the data inserted ? through your application ?

Answer (score 1):

You can **create a new service** which polls for new records and/or new folders, and then starts the existing service accordingly.

For the database, most likely you'd simply verify the row count or the latest ID in a given table periodically, for instance every 5 seconds or whatever your acceptable window is. If your database is a SQL Server database, you can also use the `SqlDependency` class. There is more about that on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) and the Code Project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events).

For the folder, you can use the `FileSystemWatcher` class to notify you of any changes (here is an example of how to do that: http://snipplr.com/view/54606).